# Add URL Links to an Image array

Tags: php, arrays, image, hyperlink, slide

I am working on this website [poochclub.com](http://www.poochclub.com) and I want to add links to each of the top image slides on the home page.

My code calls the images through an array, so I wanted to know if it is possible to add specific links to the image slides so if you click on the image they go to a product page?

This is my code:

```
<?php 
                $images = array('welcome.png', 'christmas.png', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg');
                //shuffle($images);
                $i = 0;
                foreach ($images as $im): ?>
                <img src="<?= $theme ?>/images/home/carousel-<?= $im ?>" />
            <?php $i++; endforeach ?>
```

Comment: Where are the links that you want to add stored to?

Comment: what is the link of the product page? just wrap the `<img>` with an `<a>`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can perhaps use an associative array, In which case, your code would look something like this:

```
<?php 
        $images = array('welcome.png' => 'link1', 'christmas.png'=> 'link2') 
        //shuffle($images);
        $i = 0;
        foreach ($images as $key => $value): ?>
        <a href="<?php $value ?>"><img src="<?= $theme ?>/images/home/carousel-<?= $key ?></a>" />
    <?php $i++; endforeach ?>
```

I did this pretty quickly, so i'm not sure if there's any errors, but that's the general idea.

Answer (score 0):

Like this:

```
<?php 
            $images = array('welcome.png', 'christmas.png', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg');
            //shuffle($images);
            $i = 0;
            foreach ($images as $im): ?>
            <a href="<?php $yourLink ?>"><img src="<?= $theme ?>/images/home/carousel-<?= $im ?></a>" />
        <?php $i++; endforeach ?>
```

`$yourLink` Will need to come from from your database or other location

Comment: What if 'yourlink' was stored in another array? say $links = array('link1', 'link2'.. etc)..

Comment: @AnPel - I was editing as you added that comment. :) You're right, it all depends on the source. Since it's not specified, the above example should get the OP started

Comment: In the case of an array source, say $links, since there is a counter, it can be done like: <a href="<?php echo $links[i] ?>"...

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$images = array('welcome.png', 'christmas.png', '2.jpg', '3.jpg', '4.jpg', '5.jpg', '6.jpg');

$links= array('link0.html', 'link1.html', 'link2.html', 'link3.html', 'link4.html', 'link5.html', 'link6.html');

for ($i=0 ; $i<count($images) ; $i++) {?>
  <a href="<?= $links[$i] ?>"><img src="<?= $theme ?>/images/home/carousel-<?= $images[i] ?>" /></a>
<?php } ?>
```